# Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

So I am currently creating a simple rock paper scissors game and i have hit a small snag, I have made a function for the users choice and i only allow them to select the three valid option for the game. However I experience a weird issue whenever they select something not allowed. This is my function,

```
def userChoice():

  choice = input("Rock (R), Paper (P), Scissors (S)? ")

  if choice.upper() == 'R' or choice.lower() == 'rock':
    choice = 'Rock'
    return choice

  elif choice.upper() == 'P' or choice.lower() == 'paper':
    choice = 'Paper'
    return choice

  elif choice.upper() == 'S' or choice.lower() == 'scissors':
    choice = 'Scissors'
    return choice

  else:
    print("This was an invalid option, please try again.")
    userChoice()


user = userChoice()
print("Your choice is: " + user)
```

The problem I am having is that when the user picks something they shouldn't for example 'L' it displays the error message and restarts the function allowing them to pick again. However when they pick the next time (a correct value) I get the following error.

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 23, in 
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly"

And i know if you do not return a value to a function it returns the default value of 'None' which is the Type error that I am having. However what I do not understand is why the second time it is running after the first incorrect value when i put a correct one in it still takes the value 'None' instead of the new correct value I assign?

Any help on why this occurs and how I can fix it?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: You need to return userChoice at the end. Otherwise your function will return None.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the method recursively, you need to return that value:

```
def userChoice():

  choice = input("Rock (R), Paper (P), Scissors (S)? ")

  if choice.upper() == 'R' or choice.lower() == 'rock':
    choice = 'Rock'
    return choice

  elif choice.upper() == 'P' or choice.lower() == 'paper':
    choice = 'Paper'
    return choice

  elif choice.upper() == 'S' or choice.lower() == 'scissors':
    choice = 'Scissors'
    return choice

  else:
    print("This was an invalid option, please try again.")
    # return this!
    return userChoice()


user = userChoice()
print("Your choice is: " + user)
```

If you fail to return, then the result of that function never gets returned all the way back out. Therefore, the result returned is None, and you get the error you're seeing.

A few other notes. There's no real reason to store the corrected choice in `choice`. You also can simplify the check you're doing by setting the case of `choice` once when you receive the value, sticking with it, and using that value the whole time:

```
def userChoice():

  choice = input("Rock (R), Paper (P), Scissors (S)? ").lower()

  if choice == 'r' or choice == 'rock':
    return 'Rock'

  elif choice == 'p' or choice == 'paper':
    return 'Paper'

  elif choice == 's' or choice == 'scissors':
    return 'Scissors'

  else:
    print("This was an invalid option, please try again.")
    return userChoice()
```

Comment: That's wonderful thank you for that, it worked perfectly. Thanks for explaining too!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late to reply, but @Jamie Counsell is correct in that you need to return your recursive call to userChoice(); however, you could enhance your program further by utilizing regex so that it doesn't require such specific entries. As a bonus, using it over equality checks that utilize upper() or lower(), is more efficient. Here is an example of how

```
from re import match

def userChoice():
    choice = ""
    while len(choice) < 1:
        choice = input("Rock (R), Paper (P), or Scissors (S)?\n")
    if match(r"(?i)^p(aper)?\Z", choice) is not None:
        return "Paper"
    elif match(r"(?i)^r(ock)?\Z", choice) is not None:
        return "Rock"
    elif match(r"(?i)^s(cissors)?\Z", choice) is not None:
        return "Scissors"
    else:
        print(choice + " is not a valid option, please try again.")
        return userChoice()

user = userChoice()
print("Your choice is: " + user)
```

Here's a crash course in how it works:

`match(r"", str) is not None` returns `True` if it's a match

`(?i)` denotes that the check is not case sensitive

`^` denotes the beginning of the str

`(str)?` denotes 0-1 of str

`\Z` denotes the end of the str

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to cast the variable to string. 
I have used str(variable) to cast the variable. You can cast the way you want. And now the value of variable which was pointing to nothing will start pointing to None upon casting. And the exception will disappear